# How to check if a function has been assigned?

Tags: solidity, data-types

I want to check if the callback has been assigned to avoid the exception:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.20;

contract Test {

  function() external callback;

  function test() public  {
    if (/*check here that callback is assigned*/)  {
        callback();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really. The typical way to do this is check if the call throws, and if it does, it's either unimplemented or there was an error in it.

Hopefully in the future we get to the point where reverts include reasoning, i.e. a contract can return the error saying "i don't implement this" or "there was a failure in the function call". This functionality (revert with return data) currently exists in the EVM, but Solidity hasn't implemented it yet (aside from in solidity assembly).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it would be useful to also have try-catch in Solidity. I suspect in some cases it's not possible e.g. on out-of-gas, but in other cases there should be no problem.